# How to define Iterators for an abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator, abstract-class

I'm working on a C++ project where  I have an abstract class called `Aggregate`, which represents a container for another abstract class called `Primitive`.

I want to be able to iterate through an `Aggregate`, without worrying with the details of how the `Primitive` objects are actually stored.

Since I'm not really proficient with C++, I have two questions:

- First, is it even possible to do something like this?
- Second, what exactly should my `Aggregate` class and its derived classes do in order for this to work?

Any explanation/references are very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need to be have a custom container? C++ comes with a bunch already.

Comment: Since you cannot create objects of abstract classes your `Aggregate` will have to store pointers to such objects. So your iterator will also have to provide the user with these pointers

Comment: The question seems a bit vague, not sure what exactly you want to do or what exactly the difficulty is. As always you can use virtual functions to implement whatever interface you need. Iterators may implement functionality by calling virtual functions as well.

Comment: @sweenish, yes. I didn't mention it, but `Aggregate` isn't only a container. It can have other properties relevant to the project hidden beneath is container interface.

Comment: And those properties can't be separated into their own classes? The design is starting to smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - First, is it even possible to do something like this?
> - Second, what exactly should my Aggregate class and its derived classes do in order for this to work?

Yes, you "simply" add to `Aggregate` two virtual functions returning a `begin()` and an `end()` iterator.

```cpp
struct Aggregate
{
    struct iterator { /* ... */ };
    virtual ~Aggregate() {}
    virtual iterator begin() { return {}; }
    virtual iterator end() { return begin(); }
};
```

You can then use range for loops and algorithms from the Standard Library for "free":

```cpp
for (auto& p : aggregate) {
    p.value = 0;
}

std::copy(aggregate.begin(), aggregate.end(), aggregate_copy.begin());
```

You'd need some boilerplate code to implement a working iterator though, but you'll manage with a good Google search.

[Working demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90a42452f101aeea)